# How to get a table in bootstrap to have two columns and a row underneath

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm using a ng-repeat to loop through some data to show on a table. I want the format to be 2 columns and 1 row under the 2 columns...

Right now I have:

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped">
     <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="file in files">
             <td>{{file}}<br>
             </td>
             <td>{{file.name}}</td>
             <td>{{file.error.message}}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: post the `files` array

Comment: its just an array with strings in it....looking more for styling help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`...

```
  <tr ng-repeat-start="f in files">
    <td>{{file}}</td> 
    <td>{{file.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end="">
    <td colspan="2">
      {{file.error.message}}
    </td>
  </tr>
```

[Demo (using sample user data)](http://www.codeply.com/go/2T6YPKfYsi)

Comment: woah did not know there was a start and an end for ng-repeat...thanks!